# elastic search. using scroll method to read large dataset but "scan" as search type is not working

Tags: r

First two lines of the code works. When I set search_type as "scan", it says "Error: 400 - No search type for [scan]"

```
Search('shakespeare', q="a*")$hits$total
#> [1] 2747
res <- Search(index = 'shakespeare', q="a*", scroll="1m")
res <- Search(index = 'shakespeare', q="a*", scroll="1m", search_type = "scan")
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_removed

The scan search type was deprecated since version 2.1.0 and is now removed.